# Why do I always have to clean my solution after I make a change in order for breakpoints to be hit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have had the issue that I have to always clean then build my solution after I make a change in order for breakpoints to be hit?

It only happens in a certain project and as far as I can tell my other projects have the same setup. I am using Vs13 and coding in c#.

I receive an error saying that the pages are different to source and cannot be debugged.

Am I incorrect in saying that with minor changes simply hitting F5 will build my changes and run with debugging?

I have been searching for a while for a solution any help would be awesome :).

Comment: Check your build output and see if all projects are built and not just the startup project. Are you sure the project which you made changes is the startup project or is directly referenced in the startup project?

Comment: Only 3 projects are being built when hit F5 out of 16(One project is startup one is where the change is). Is it important that im making changes in a project that is not my start up project? How do i check if its directly referenced?

Comment: It is important point, if you are making changes in a non startup project, because if the project is not directly referenced and VS doesn't know that startup project has dependency on it, it might not build it when you press `F5`. Check the `Project Dependencies` dialog from project menu and choose your startup project from the dropdown and see if the changed project is listed as a dependency. if not you'll have to mark it as one to force a build when you start debugging of startup project.

Comment: The project in question is already ticked :(

Comment: Doing `CTRL+SHIFT+B` (build solution) before `F5` (start debugging) builds (only) the changed project and it's dependencies?

Comment: It does not make a difference if i do F5 Build Or CTRL+SHIFT+B Build I always have to clean the solution then build to get it hit break points or build it either way then run then stop build it anyway again then run and it works.

Comment: Did you ever found the solution ? I have the exact same problem now in VS 2019

Comment: @GuidoG Honestly mate I cant remember that was almost a decade ago sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that because the source code has to be built to reflect your new changes. The debugger can't match up the built code with the source

Comment: I understand that, but shouldn't a build do this? Why do i have to build and clean? In other projects i don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you need to rebuild the solution and not just build the individual project that has changed. I usually run into this when the assembly of the project I changed is referenced by some other project and the assembly for the modified project is not copied over (in my case all compiled assemblies get copied over only when solution rebuild is successful). Also, sometimes accidentally I would just build the start project and not necessarily the one I made changes to.

It is important to understand the difference between build and rebuild. Build will compile only those files that have changed since the last change. Building the project is faster than rebuilding. Rebuild will clean all files and rebuild all projects from scratch, regardless of whether they changed or not.

Comment: Building straight after a change then running results in the same situation(no breakpoints code is different) however if I make a change then build then run then build then run there is no error. :S

Comment: I should note that the second build output normally says 0 projects where changed.